# Changing the TCP Destination address using WinDivert or PyDivert

Tags: routing, python, tcp, redirection, c

I'm trying to "route" TCP traffic by using WinDivert to change the Destination Address (and port) of certain outbound traffic.

I began with using PyDivert as I am a total and complete programming noob. I was able to get the examples working, where the port was modified before getting sent out. However I could not get that working with a changed destination IP address.

My goal is to redirect the TCP packets from a program through a linux machine/server and then to the original destination of those packets. Pretty much rerouting the traffic!

I think the issue I was getting is that I was not handling the "path back" but I was not sure how to do that. Is that controlled in the outbound packet contents? Or will the packet find it's way back and I would have to filter and change the inbound packet?

Thank you everyone!